# What would be a better use case or improved way to write this in a function?

Tags: arrays, json, vb.net, visual-studio, bigcommerce

I have a JArray inside of a function that will return the JArray
Here's the JSON Example:

```
    {
  "data": {
    "availability": "available",
    "availability_description": "",
    "base_variant_id": null,
    "bin_picking_number": "1234",
    "brand_id": 1,
    "calculated_price": 9.99,
    "categories": [
      98765,
      87654,
      76543
    ],
    "condition": "New",
    "cost_price": 0,
    "custom_url": {
      "is_customized": false,
      "url": "/stackoverflowtest/"
    },
```

Connected to API, Returning JSON ->

```
Function GetProductCategories(productid As String) As JArray
    Dim returnCatArray As JArray
    Try
        Using response As System.Net.WebResponse = request.GetResponse()
            Using streamReader As System.IO.StreamReader = New System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
                Dim jsonResponseText = streamReader.ReadToEnd()
                Dim tokenJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonResponseText)
                Dim jsonResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Dictionary(Of String, Object))(jsonResponseText)
                Dim ary = JArray.FromObject(jsonResult.Item("data").item(0).value(Of Object)("categories"))
                returnCatArray = ary
            End Using
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try

    Return returnCatArray
End Function
```

How would you call this if you wanted to tie each index into an additional search from another API
For example. lets say the array count is 2 - each of the items in the array will get compared to something else that belongs in another API, I have an idea of how to do this, but in using this function would it be best to loop this through it's own index? I'm only asking all of this to make sure i'm doing best practices with this.

```
For each idx in GetProductCategories("123456")
   GetCategorySpecificInfoById("123456")
Next
```

Would it be something along the lines of this concept?

Comment: *Connected to API, Returning JSON*: you get a JSON, so what is this for: `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonResponseText)`? -- Why don't you build a class model and deserialize the JSON to that directly?

Comment: Dim jResults As JObject = JObject.Parse(jsonResponseText)
Dim naming As [String] = jResults("data")("name") <- Like this?

Comment: It currently resides in a class model right now, it's left out of the code provided

Comment: What does *currently resides in a class model* means? You're not using any model to deserialize your JSON response.  You'd have something like: `Dim myModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of MyModelRoot)(jsonResponseText)`. If you don't want to use a data model and just need the `categories` array as an `Integer()`, then you can write, e.g., `dim categories as Integer() = JObject.Parse(jsonResponseText)("data")("categories").ToObject(Of Integer())()`. BUT, your JSON is incomplete, as posted here, hence the method depends on the structure of the real JSON.

Comment: Oh I misunderstood Jimi, Apologizes! For grabbing the contents of the array, I define it by ("data")("id") and then parse it to JArray from objects. jsonResult is being passed to this instance as well, it's being deserialized correctly on my end, but again I want to use best practice and for whatever reason it feels messy.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what you're referring to. You're mentioning stuff that is not included in the questions and possibly also referring to the complete JSON, with properties I cannot see. -- In relation to what you posted here, my previous comment shows how to deserialize the `categories` array to an `Integer()` array. -- I suggest to work with .Net classes instead of trying to handle Json.Net objects (also consider that you may decide or have to change the Serializer, at some point, so what you have done means nothing then).

Comment: My Question has been answered. Thank you for all of your help, Jimi.

Comment: @TJPendarvis Could you share and accept the solution in the answer?